# 2014 Kia Soul Ignition Lock Cylinder

Tags: ignition, kia, cylinder

My car was recently vandalized (failed theft attempt) and they messed up my ignition lock cylinder. I have to replace it with a new one. Over the past year, Kia and Hyundai have been targeted for thefts which has created a very severe parts shortage. I've already waited 6 weeks for the part to come in and the manufacturer has not confirmed any release date. Because I'm getting desperate I've been considering buying a used salvage part to get me rolling for the mean time. My car is a 2014 Kia Soul Base, automatic, no fog lamps, 1.6L engine, no push button start, has a flip key with remote to unlock/lock doors.

My question is: do I have to use the exact part # as the one that is recommended by the dealership for my vin? Or can I use an ignition lock cylinder that is from a different year but same model maybe different trim? As of now the options I am seeing for my type of car with keyed ignition are 81905-B2000 , 81905-B2110, 81905-B2111 . The one the dealership is waiting on is 81905-B2110. I'm hoping the other options could also work.

Please someone help to expand my search. Feels like trying to find a needle in a hay stack.

Answer (score 0):

Good ol' Hyundai and Kia...
They like to make a mess of their key systems.

The only difference I see between B2000 and B2110 looks like
B2000 comes with 2 standard keys where B2110 comes with 2 remote flip keys.

B2000 I think should work but a lot of places say they will confirm based on your VIN. You should check with one of those sellers first to be sure. Like this [seller on eBay](https://%20https://www.ebay.com/itm/394122859515?mkcid=1&mkrid=711-53200-19255-0&siteid=0&campid=5338826782&customid=&toolid=10001&mkevt=1).

I'm not sure if this [Kia parts supplier](https://www.kiacheapparts.com/v-2014-kia-soul--base--1-6l-l4-gas) has any in stock but you could probably search using your VIN to see which part it pulls up.

If you are in the US. There should be no immobilizer so just getting the part and installing it is enough. If your in other parts of the world, it will be equipped with an immobilizer and the keys will need to be programmed. This will be a different part number because the the b2000's I see do not come with chipped keys.